# Error de rutas en localhost

Tags: laravel, ajax

tengo un problema y es que cuando uso la *URL* de *localhost* me da error en todas las rutas que manejo desde *ajax*. Lo raro es que cuando lo ejecuto mediante el comando *phpartisan server* funcionan perfectamente, se los agradezco estoy usando laravel en su version 8.

Comment: Sin un  [mcve] poco podemos hacer por ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente porque con php artisan utilices rutas:
**localhost:8000/catalogo**

y con xampp/wamp utilizar rutas:
**localhost/my_proyecto/public/catalogo**

**Solución 1**
Se puede solucionar si creas un subdominio que apunte a la carpeta public de tu proyecto.

**Solución 2**
También puedes utilizar la función [route de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) y busques la ruta por el nombre:

```
{{route('nombre_de_la_ruta')}}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo ambas funcinaron.